# Access Custom Layout Elements Within AlertDialog Builder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating an alert dialog within one of my Java classes and I have it pull from a custom layout. I want to set the PositiveButton to use elements within the layout to fill my Task object (i.e. editName, editDesc). The issue is that I don't know how to pull them from within the builder. Pulling them from the root simply crashes the app.

````
// Functionality for AddTask Button
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // A builder that will create a new dialog using our add task layout
                AlertDialog.Builder addTaskDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                addTaskDialog.setTitle("Add Task")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_task_dialog, null))
                        .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                            {
                                // Get our inputs
                                EditText editName = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.editTaskName);
                                EditText editDesc = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.editTaskDesc);

                                // DO STUFF
                                ArrayList<Category> cats = new ArrayList<Category>();
                                cats.add(Category.CATEGORY00);
                                cats.add(Category.CATEGORY02);
                                cats.add(Category.CATEGORY05);

                                long date = 01022021L;

                                Task testTask = new TaskSingle(editName.getText().toString(), editDesc.getText().toString(), Difficulty.EASY, cats, Color.AQUA, date, false);

                                mTasks.add(testTask);
                                mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

                // Show out dialog
                addTaskDialog.show();
            }
        });```
````

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own issue. The trick was to cast the dialoginterface that gets passed to the onClick function and cast it as AlertDialog:

```
.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
   {
      // Get our inputs
      EditText editName = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.editTaskName);
      EditText editDesc = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.editTaskDesc);
```